# retrieving saved url in cookie for body background jquery

Tags: jquery, css, url, cookies

I am trying to retrieve a saved url from a jquery cookie 
its saving in the cookie but its not retrieving the cookie url

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#BGSelector a").click(function() {
    var imgLink = $("img", this).attr("src");
        $.cookie("html_img", "" + imgLink + "", { expires: 7 });
        var imgCookieLink = $.cookie("html_img");
        $("html").css("background", "url('" + imgCookieLink + "')"); }); });
```

thanks to xandy for the jquery script

Comment: i know it working but, its not staying with the pic, if you go to another link, refresh, or come back to same page, the pic is gone

Comment: In your code background is applying when link is clicked.If u want to apply background by refreshing the page,write this below lines in ready function.
  var imgCookieLink = $.cookie("html_img");
  $("html").css("background", "url('" + imgCookieLink + "')");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#BGSelector a").click(function() {
       var imgLink = $("img", this).attr("src");
       $.cookie("html_img", "" + imgLink + "", { expires: 7 });
       var imgCookieLink = $.cookie("html_img");
       $("html").css("background", "url('" + imgCookieLink + "')"); 
    }); 
 });
 </script>


<div id="BGSelector" >
<a href="javascript:;"><img src="images.jpeg" /></a>
</div>
```

This is working in my browser.once check your code.

Comment: ok than how can i make t so, it will retrieve this link after the user leaves and comes back, so it will be retrieving this link always when pages load

Answer (score 0):

this is funny all i did was call the cookie again

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
   var imgCookieLink = $.cookie("html_img");  
   $("html").css("background", "url('" + imgCookieLink + "')"); 
 });

</script>
```